# changing alias to python3 in zsh

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, zsh

I am using zsh shell and I am trying to change default python in my mac which is currently python2.

I am getting the following:

```
➜ alias python = 'python3'
zsh: bad assignment
```

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the whitespace before and after the equal sign.

```bash
alias python='python3'
```

As a sidenote, you'll want to put this line in the `.zshrc` file if you want the alias to persist.